# How to fix this ngon?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

[image]

[image: ngon]

[image]

I have Mesh Check Addon which says that I have a bad polygon (red vertex). How can I fix it? When I triangulate all faces and set Shading: smooth,  black shadows appear on the model.

Comment: Just for clarification of the terms: It's either a polygon or a vertex, two different things. You most likely have double vertices somewhere or at least vertices that are very close to each other, that could be merged. It's hard to tell from the screenshot. You might want to upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then edit your question ([edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135401/edit) below it) and add the link given by blend-exchange to your text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just switch to *Wireframe* mode <kbd>Z</kbd>, box-select the general are (don't grab anything useful), then merge it at center with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Afterwards use snap to vertex on the individual axis, to make sure it ends up back in place.